# JQuery Qtip2 text over multiple lines (in Django project)

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, qtip2

I am trying to integrate QTip2 tooltips into my Django template.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category_1").qtip({
    content: {
        text: '{{ categories.category_1_helptext }}'
        }
    });
});
```

This works very well, as long as the helptext in the database is only one line long. Is there a way to use a string over two lines with QTip2? Things like `<br>` or "\n" don't work.

Comment: What exactly is the `category_1_helptext` value, does it come from CharField or TextField?

Comment: You can set the width of the tooltips so that it will flow to two lines http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=1342

Comment: `category_1_helptext` is a TextField. I would like the user to be able to enter multiple line strings there, in the worst case I would have to convert it in the views.py before passing it on to the template (eg adding \n to each line).

Comment: Setting the width doesn't help - I would like to show the exact line breaks as in the TextField

Comment: Not really a Django issue - just a CSS one. You can word wrap with some CSS3 - word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `<br>` doesn't work? If I use `|linebreaksbr` filter, it breaks lines very clearly.

Comment: Thanks - I was so stuck on thinking this must be a problem with QTip2, but did not think this could be due to Django's security stuff when passing HTML to the template...